# VBA conditions for a UserForm

Tags: vba, if-statement, integer

I am new on VBA. I want to put some restrictions on my inputs in the UserForm. I want My variable to be a number (the user should select the row Number) and if she/he put text or leave it blank an error message should appear. This is the code I have:

```
Public Sub AddPolicy_Click()
Dim RowNumber As Integer
RowNumber = TextBox1.Value
If RowNumber = "" Then
    MsgBox "Error Row Number- enter a value!", vbOKCancel + vbCritical, "Error"
ElseIf VarType(RowNumber) = vbString Then
    MsgBox "Error Row Number- enter a  Numerical Value!", vbOKCancel + vbCritical, "Error"
End If
Range("A1") = RowNumber
End Sub
```

I know that the problem is because I declare my variable RowNumber as an Integer, But if I do not do that the software does not recognize my variable, and show me the error message for text, blank and number. SO I do not know how can I solve this.

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
Public Sub AddPolicy_Click()
Dim RowNumber As String
RowNumber = TextBox1.Value
If RowNumber = "" Then
    MsgBox "Error Row Number- enter a value!", vbOKCancel + vbCritical, "Error"
ElseIf Not IsNumeric(RowNumber) Then
    MsgBox "Error Row Number- enter a  Numerical Value!", vbOKCancel + vbCritical, "Error"
End If
Range("A1") = RowNumber
End Sub
```

Edit: About the declaration of String, integer etc.: I know people tend to be very particular about this. But it really doesnt make a difference efficiency-wise for most macros. Here for example you wont gain anything by declaring it better. Even simply not dim'ing it would work nicely.

Comment: Hello. Thank you so much. It worked. I have a question. So basically, in the "ElseIf not" you said: if it is not a number (and because RowNumber As String) then show the other message?

Comment: Edit: I misunderstood. Yes you are right. Also actually IsNumeric() excepts strings without giving you errors. So even if you give it something like "123" instead of 123 it will evaluate it as numeric. But KS123 will fail the IsNumeric check and then display the second msgbox.

Comment: I'd definitely `Dim` all variables - I'd strongly recommend clicking "Require Variable Declaration" in the VBE options (so you get `Option Explicit` at the top of each module).  If you type `RoNumber` instead of `RowNumber` anywhere in the code it will happily create that variable for you and you'll spend ages wondering why your variable doesn't contain the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this code.
The change event on the textbox will stop you being able to enter anything except numerics.

```
Private LastText As String '<-- place this at the very top of the module.

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    With Me.TextBox1
        'Allow only whole numbers.
        If .Text Like "[!0-9]" Or Val(.Text) < -1 Or .Text Like "?*[!0-9]*" Then
            .Text = LastText
        Else
            LastText = .Text
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_AfterUpdate()
    'Remove any leading or trailing spaces
    '(although the Change event should stop you entering spaces).
    Me.TextBox1 = Trim(Me.TextBox1)
End Sub

Private Sub AddPolicy_Click()
    With Me.TextBox1
        If .Value <> "" Then
            'Fully qualify where you want to put the data, or it will
            'put it in A1 of whichever sheet happens to be active.
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = Me.TextBox1
        Else
            MsgBox "Invalid or no value entered.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```